# A custom layer with a input kernel and bias

Tags: keras, layer

I have a problem when implementing a customized conv2d layer with a input kernel and bias. This kernel and bias are the outputs of another layer A, then using these weights to do a conv2d. And I just want this layer to use the weight rather rather to learn, so if this layer is not trainable, will the gradient be transferred to the layer A, that means I want to the layer A be trainable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to write such a layer with non-learnable parameters. If I understand it correctly, you need something below.

```
import keras
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Dense, Input, Flatten, Lambda
from keras.models import Model
from keras import backend as K

img = Input(shape=(32,32,3), name='img_in')
# this is the standard way of calling a learnable conv kernel and bias
# but kernel and bias are independent of input
x = Conv2D( 64,(5,5),padding='same',name='StandardConv')(img)
# this is a custom way of calling a learnable conv kernel and bias
# but this time they are dependent on the input
img_flat = Flatten(name='flat')(img)
conv_kernel = Dense( 3*5*5*64, name='regConvKernel' )( img_flat )
conv_bias = Dense( 64, name='regConvBias' )( img_flat )
# of course, you need to use conv_kernel and conv_bias to apply conv operation
# and this happens here
def custom_conv( input_vars ) :
    x, kernel, bias = input_vars
    kernel = K.reshape( kernel, (5,5,3,64))
    bias = K.reshape( bias, [1,1,1,64])
    x = K.conv2d( x, kernel, padding='same' )
    x += bias
    return x
def custom_conv_shape( input_shapes ) :
    x_shape, kernel_shape, bias_shape = input_shapes
    return x_shape[:3] + bias_shape[-1:]
y = Lambda( custom_conv, output_shape=custom_conv_shape, name='CustomConv')([img, conv_kernel, conv_bias])
# define your final model
model = Model( inputs=img, outputs=[x,y], name='compareConv')

print model.summary()

# test use dummy numpy arrays
import numpy as np 
a = np.random.randn(1,32,32,3)
b, c = model.predict(a)
print "standard conv output shape =", b.shape
print "custom conv output shape =", c.shape
```

And you shall see outputs like below.

```
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
img_in (InputLayer)             (None, 32, 32, 3)    0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flat (Flatten)                  (None, 3072)         0           img_in[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
regConvKernel (Dense)           (None, 4800)         14750400    flat[0][0]                       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
regConvBias (Dense)             (None, 64)           196672      flat[0][0]                       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
StandardConv (Conv2D)           (None, 32, 32, 64)   4864        img_in[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
CustomConv (Lambda)             (None, 32, 32, 64)   0           img_in[0][0]                     
                                                                 regConvKernel[0][0]              
                                                                 regConvBias[0][0]                
==================================================================================================
Total params: 14,951,936
Trainable params: 14,951,936
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
None
standard conv output shape = (1, 32, 32, 64)
custom conv output shape = (1, 32, 32, 64)
```

Of course, you may use a different kernel size or padding scheme. And you may consider more reasonable way to estimate `conv_kernel` and `conv_bias` rather than directly regressing them from input.

Comment: Thanks very much! Your idea is very perfect! So in this way, the conv_kernel and conv_bias are just the output from a Dense layer and to optimize the weights of those fc layers. And my kernel and bias are from the h5 file of another model, I use the weights of already trained model's classifier, so do you know whether I can use a fixed input in keras and this input only given once rather than the way of giving batch size images. Thanks!

Comment: Of course, you can. All you need to do is to define `conv_kernel` and `conv_bias` as `keras` variables directly, e.g. `import numpy as np
val = np.random.random((3, 4, 5))
conv_kernel = K.variable(value=val)`

Comment: Hi, I am wondering if I use a TimeDistributed layer to wrap the Lambda() which call the customconv, the input_x is a 5D tensor, but the kernel and bias are not, if I expand the dimension of kernel and bias which seems not reasonable?

Comment: If you should be fine because you are using the `TimeDistributed( XXX )` layer, which will treat your input's 2nd dimension as the time dimension and feed a 4D input to the `XXX` layer.

Comment: But you know that the shape of input of the TimeDistributed should be larger than 3, and if I give a list like [input_x, kernel, bias] may throw an error, maybe the list should be 5D, but I don't have any idea now.

Comment: Hi, I think that TimeDistributed() is needed, if writing a custom_layer, then the kernel and bias can be used similar as the "strides, padding", so there is only one input. But I am still concern about whether the gradient will be transferred to up layers where output the kernel and bias?